# CS50 Pset 5 (speller): Initialization of variable as char or char*?

Tags: arrays, c, char, cs50, c-strings

I've completed CS50 PS5 (speller). I understand the program except for one line of code in the load function. The syntax seems trivial but I'd like to understand what's going on.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open dictionary
    FILE *d_pointer = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (d_pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open %s\n.", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // Variable for scanned words
    char w_scan[LENGTH + 1];

    // Scan words from dictionary
    while (fscanf(d_pointer, "%s", w_scan) != EOF)
    {

        // Create new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Copy word into node
        strcpy(n->word, w_scan);

        // Hash word
        int h_value = hash(w_scan);

        // Insert node into hash table
        n->next = table[h_value];
        table[h_value] = n;
        d_size++;
    }

    // Close dictionary
    fclose(d_pointer);

    return true;
}
```

My questions is, why does the variable that represents scanned words (w_scan) have to be initialized as a char and not a string? If I replace the initialization of w_scan as char *w_scan instead of char w_scan I get the following error:

```
dictionary.c:83:36: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Werror,-Wformat] while (fscanf(d_pointer, "%s", w_scan) != EOF)
```

Sorry for the basic question. I'm obviously missing something here but I'm scratching my head as to what I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions is, why does the variable that represents scanned words (w_scan) have to be initialized as a char and not a string?

It is not being initialized as a `char`.  It is being initialized as *an array* of `char`, which is exactly the type of object that holds a string.  Which brings me to a second important point: data type **`char *` does not represent a string**.  A string is a sequence of one or more `char`s, up to and including a terminator with value 0.  Objects of type `char *` are useful for referring to strings, but they must not be confused with the strings themselves.  This is in the category of distinguishing between the pointer and the thing to which it points.

If you instead write

```
    char *w_scan[LENGTH + 1];
```

then you thereby declare an array of pointers, not an array of `char`.  That might in some cases be exactly what you want, but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Sadly, cs50 pounds into new students the incorrect assumption that `char *` and 'string' are synonymous, so much so there is a type-alias of the latter to the former (not kidding; `typedef char *string;` is a cornerstone of their official header). That thing has done more damage to more beginning C programmers, I swear.

Comment: Yes, @WhozCraig, I am aware, and I find it deplorable.  But I chose not to raise that issue in this answer directly because I see no sign in the question that the OP is relying on CS50's `string` typedef.  Nevertheless, you're right that they may have been influenced by that.

Comment: Ahhhh, this makes complete sense now! Thank you so much for clarifying. And unfortunately, yes, the reason I thought this syntax should have been "char * w_scan" was because of how the char and string data types were explained in CS50.

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
char w_scan[LENGTH + 1];
```

there is declared an array of `LENGTH + 1` characters that is used to read words from a file in a loop  by means of this call

```
fscanf(d_pointer, "%s", w_scan)
```

This declaration

```
char * w_scan[LENGTH + 1];
```

does not make a sense. The function reads sequences of characters not sequences of pointers.